# C++20 support in C++/CLI and alternatives

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, interop

I was wondering if anyone knows about a timeline or expected release for C++20 support in C++/CLI. According to this [answer in the microsoft developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-C20-or-higher-under-CCLI/10173878#T-ND10217784) support is in development, but i couldn't find more information.

Background:
Me and my team are developing a simulation engine in C++. We were thinking about a wrapping layer in C++/CLI so we can use C# for the UI/Editor. This is similar to the architecture of some game engines, where the main functionality is implemented in C++ and the Editor is written in C# and there is some layer in between.
Because we would heavily rely on further support of C++/CLI, are there any alternatives for this kind of project?
We were expecting there is some more information on the Microsoft forums and websites, but have problems finding something that really fits our purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++20 support, as well as support for C++11 threading, will be added in MSVC 2022 17.6.

From https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog#expected-in-vs-2022-176-preview-1 :

> The STL now supports /clr for C++11 multithreading (mutex, condition_variable, future, etc.) and C++17 parallel algorithms. Additionally, the STL now allows /clr to be used in C++20 mode, although this is not yet supported for production use. #3194 #3201
>
> See tracking issue #3193 for a list of compiler bugs that affect these newly enabled /clr scenarios.

Note, as stated in the above quote, the C++20 with `/clr` is **not** ready for production. That will come in a later release, but there's no estimates on that yet.

Assuming MS keeps with their 3 month release cycle, 17.5 will be released in February, meaning 17.6 preview 1 will be available at the same time, with a general release in May.